# Payflow Pro Express Checkout. How to skip first page?

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I want that CC payments been processed by Paypal. As I understood if user will enter his cc data on first page (fig. 1), it will be processed by FDMS. And if user will click "Checkout with PayPal" and will input cc information on the second page (fig. 2) it will processed by PayPal. How can I skip first page? Or tell me please if there are any other solutions?

**Reason why I want that CC payment been processed by PayPal - is to get instant payment notifications.**

[image: First page]
Fig. 1 - First page
[image: Second page]
Fig. 2 - Second page

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to use the Hosted Solution product? The first screen shot makes it look like you are. There are different layouts for the Hosted Solution checkout method but they all have some variation of that landing page first.

The only way to avoid that first page is to use the Express Checkout product on its own without using the Hosted Solution at all. Your buyers would be redirected to the page in the second screen shot right away.

You will get IPN posts when payments are made through the credit card form or the Express Checkout page. PayPal is the gateway for both methods.

Comment: "The only way to avoid that first page is to use the Express Checkout" Thanks. :(

Comment: Sorry, brother. The Hosted Solution page is designed to be a credit card or PayPal checkout process in the way displayed the first screen shot. Using the separate Express Checkout call gets ride of that first page but it wouldn't be using the Hosted Solution you're paying for.